# Extract the byte array of Zip files sent from C # in Objective-c side

Tags: c#, objective-c, unity-game-engine, gzip, unzip

It passes from C # a byte array of Zip files via Plugin in Objective-c,
I want to thaw in Objective-c side, but we are suffering not go well.
Byte data that has been converted into NSData type using Zlib to the following URL reference
It is tried to thaw but, inflate (& stream, Z_NO_FLUSH); of
After a review of our return value, what would have been returned is Z_DATA_ERROR that data that can not be decompressed by zlib is determined to have been input does not know the cause, please tell me if there are people with knowledge

■ URL

https://gist.github.com/hacha/9207616

http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

---

SourceCode(C#)

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class CallPlugin : MonoBehaviour {

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void uncompressByGzip(byte[] zipbytearray,int ziplen);


    public void CallMain(byte[] unZipStream,int unZipLength){

        uncompressByGzip (unZipStream,unZipLength);
        Debug.Log ("Test CSharp");
    }
}
```

SourceCode(Objective-C)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#include <zlib.h>


extern "C"{
    void uncompressByGzip(const char** ptrSrc, const int srcLength);
}


void uncompressByGzip(const char** ptrSrc, const int srcLength)
{
    NSData *source = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)ptrSrc length:(sizeof(unsigned char) * srcLength)];

    NSString* str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",srcLength];
    NSLog(@"src = %@",str);
    if (source.length == 0)
        return;
    NSLog(@"11111");

    z_stream stream;
    stream.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    stream.zfree = Z_NULL;
    stream.opaque = Z_NULL;
    stream.avail_in = (uInt)source.length;
    stream.next_in = (Bytef *)source.bytes;
    stream.total_out = 0;
    stream.avail_out = 0;

    NSLog(@"22222");
    if (inflateInit2(&stream, 31) != Z_OK)
        return;

    NSLog(@"33333");
    NSMutableData *FileSystemData = [NSMutableData dataWithCapacity:0];
    while (stream.avail_out == 0) {
        NSLog(@"12345");
        Bytef buffer[16384];
        stream.next_out = buffer;
        stream.avail_out = sizeof(buffer);
        NSString* avail_outbef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(NSInteger)stream.avail_out];
        NSLog(@"avail_outbef = %@",avail_outbef);

//        inflate(&stream, Z_FINISH);
        int ret;
        inflate(&stream,Z_NO_FLUSH);
        size_t length = sizeof(buffer) - stream.avail_out;

        avail_outbef = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(NSInteger)stream.avail_out];
        NSLog(@"avail_outaft = %@",avail_outbef);

        NSString* strlength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(NSInteger)length];
        NSLog(@"length = %@",strlength);

        if (length > 0)
            [FileSystemData appendBytes:buffer length:length];
    }
    inflateEnd(&stream);
    NSLog(@"44444");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `uncompressByGzip` function is taking a `const char**` argument for the data buffer. I'm not familiar with the marshalling behavior with the C# code, but that looks suspicious since you're passing through a `byte []`. My guess is that you want that to be a direct `const char *` instead of the indirected pointer. Certainly the call to `-[NSData dataWithBytes:length:]` expects the actual buffer, not a pointer to one.